# App crashes in native code in libicuuc.so on LG phones with Android 6.0

Tags: android, sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow, native-code, lg

My app crashes in libicuuc.so file. **It only occurs on LG phones with Android 6.0**.
I searched but I didn't find any similar problems. 
This is the stack trace from Google Play:

```
Build fingerprint: 'lge/p1bssn_global_com/p1bssn:6.0/MRA58K/1635010184e9f:user/release-keys'
Revision: '6'
ABI: 'arm'
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xba45f000
    r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 0000133b  r3 becaf54c
    r4 0000133a  r5 0000133a  r6 becaf54c  r7 becaf50c
    r8 becaf80c  r9 0000a972  sl ba45c98c  fp 9b7444bc
    ip b65d3bc0  sp becaf4d0  lr b650c821  pc b650c7d2  cpsr 00000030

backtrace:
    #00 pc 000577d2  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
    #01 pc 0005804d  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
    #02 pc 0005739f  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
    #03 pc 000a33d7  /system/lib/libicuuc.so (u_strToLower_55+130)
    #04 pc 00046997  /system/lib/libsqlite.so
```

What might be causing this error?

Comment: It seems an Internal Lib function error try this line of code in build gradle  `defaultConfig {
        ndk {
   abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86","armeabi","mips","arm64-v8a"
   //OR
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","armeabi","x86"
        }
      
    }`  it would build for all devices.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The app is already working fine on all devices. If that was the problem i suppose it should have given a UnsatisfiedLinkError error.

Comment: `"ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software."` It's crashing  in the function `u_strToLower`, so search your code for the `"ToLower"` method (in `java`), maybe you can isolate the code and the problem.

Comment: @JonGoodwin  I am calling a query on sqlite like below : "lower(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(content, 'Â','a'),'İ','i'),'Î','i'),'Û','u'),'I','i'),'Ş','s'),'Ç','c'),'Ğ','g'),'Ö','o'),'Ü','u'),'â','a'),'ş','s'),'ı','i'),'ö','o'),'ç','c'),'ü','u'),'ğ','g'),'î','i'),'û','u'))";

Comment: @JonGoodwin But it only crashes in Lg phones with Android 6.0.

Comment: Yes I read the question. Why that is is not material in the short term (unless you want to wait for LG to fix it ). We need to make your code better (e.g. regex etc) . Don't you agree ?:-)

Comment: What are some better ways to do this?   I think the solution was perfect because it was much faster than doing it on application level and didn't need an extra column where a copy of the content will be stored for search but unfortunately LG phones crash somehow.

Comment: I realized i don't actually need to use lower function. I hope the problem was indeed in toLowerCase function and not in embedded replace functions since i cannot regenerate this error without an LG phone.

Answer (score 0):

> What might be causing this error?

The juicy bits from the stack trace/back trace:

```
/system/lib/libicuuc.so
ABI: 'arm'
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xba45f000
#03 pc 000a33d7  /system/lib/libicuuc.so (u_strToLower_55+130)
```

> International Components for Unicode (ICU) is an open source project
>   of mature C/C++ and Java libraries for Unicode support, software
>   internationalization, and software globalization. ICU is widely
>   portable to many operating systems and environments. It gives
>   applications the same results on all platforms and between C, C++, and
>   Java software. The ICU project is sponsored, supported, and used by
>   IBM and many other companies. [International Components for Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode).

It's crashing in the function `u_strToLower` (SIGSEGV, segmentation fault, trying to read or write an illegal memory location), so search your code for the `"ToLower"` method (in java), maybe you can isolate the code and the problem. We can replace the call to something we can control, i.e. a `string` to `lower case` function. You should also `bullet-proof` the `string` passed to this function (is it `null` ?).

> Why is it crashing in a native library, I'm using Java ?
>
> All of that code that starts life as Java code is converted into a
>   piece of native compiled code. Technically, the classes.dex will be
>   converted into an ELF shared object. Android calls this library format
>   OAT and the tool that converts the classes.dex file is called dex2oat.
>   See this [How apps are built and run on the Android Runtime (ART)](https://medium.com/@HeadFirstDroid/how-apps-are-built-and-run-on-the-android-runtime-art-c027f73edb09).